# How can I set my Cygwin PATH to find postgresql header and library path?

Tags: bash, postgresql, path, cygwin, postgresql-8.4

I am on Windows 7 and installed **Cygwin** and **PostgresSql-8.4** on it. I have an open-source application written in C that requires to be build and for that, I am using Cygwin.

My problem is with setting the path for PostgreSql in Cygwin. As per the instruction that came with open-source, the build requires me to export path to postgreSql header and library path as follows:

**export ENV_PG_INC_PATH=/usr/include/pgsql**

**export ENV_PG_LIB_PATH=/usr/lib/pgsql**

I tried to export the same path in Windows using Cygwin as follows:

- **export ENV_PG_INC_PATH=$ENV_PG_INC_PATH:"/cygdrive/C/Program Files (x86)/PostgreSQL/8.4/include"**
- **export ENV_PG_LIB_PATH=$ENV_PG_LIB_PATH:"/cygdrive/C/Program Files (x86)/PostgreSQL/8.4/lib"**

But this doesn't seems to be working as when I try to access the dll's or any exe's inside these folders, it throws the error as follows:

**-bash: _int.dll: command not found**

I don't know what is it that I am doing wrong as I am new to Cygwin. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `bash: _int.dll: command not found` -- You seem to be attempting to *execute* a DLL??

Comment: The question is not about the execution. I need to be able to set the path to those directories using export and if I might succeed, the result would be as follows:
**-bash: /cygdrive/C/Program Files (x86)/PostgreSQL/8.4/lib/_int.dll: cannot execute binary file**

I don't have to execute any dll, just set the path correctly and proceed with the build process.

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape all spaces in file paths:

```
export ENV_PG_LIB_PATH=$ENV_PG_LIB_PATH:"/cygdrive/C/Program\ Files\ (x86)/PostgreSQL/8.4/lib"
```